# Extra wrapper in XML array

Tags: xml, arrays, serialization

I have an XML file that I must match when submitting data.  No matter what I do, I end up with an extra wrapper for the primary array.  The XML must look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<contracts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <contract>
        <productType>VSC</productType>
        <contractNumber>ABS1869169</contractNumber>
        <vehicle>
            <vin>JTKDE177160100198</vin>
            <odometer>128135</odometer>
            <purchasePrice>5574</purchasePrice>
      </vehicle>
    </contract>
    <contract>
        <productType>VSC</productType>
        <contractNumber>ABS1865421</contractNumber>
        <vehicle>
            <vin>LTGSE177160154878</vin>
            <odometer>119154</odometer>
            <purchasePrice>6509</purchasePrice>
        </vehicle>
    </contract>
</contracts>
```

I end up with an extra contracts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<contracts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <contracts>
    <contract>
      <productType>VSC</productType>
      <contractNumber>ABS1869169</contractNumber>
      <vehicle>
        <vin>JTKDE177160100198</vin>
        <odometer>128135</odometer>
        <purchasePrice>5574</purchasePrice>
      </vehicle>
    </contract>
    <contract>
      <productType>VSC</productType>
      <contractNumber>ABS1865421</contractNumber>
      <vehicle>
        <vin>LTGSE177160154878</vin>
        <odometer>119154</odometer>
        <purchasePrice>6509</purchasePrice>
      </vehicle>
    </contract>
  </contracts>
</contracts>
```

Here is the code I have.

```
Public Class contracts

    Public contracts() As contract

End Class


Public Class contract
    Public productType As String = "VSC"
    Public contractNumber As String
    Public vehicle As New contractVehicle
End Class

Public Class contractVehicle
    Public vin As String
    Public odometer As String
    Public purchasePrice As String
End Class


    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(contracts))
    Using stream As Stream = New FileStream("C:\Code\TestXML2.xml", FileMode.Create)
        Dim s As New XmlWriterSettings()
        s.Indent = True
        s.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlTextWriter.Create(stream, s)
        serializer.Serialize(writer, vx)
        writer.Close()
    End Using
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out the answer to my own question.  I just needed to set the attribute.

```
Public Class contracts

    <XmlElementAttribute("contract", Form:=Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> _
    Public contracts() As contract

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: +1 for finding out yourself *and* posting the solution. Not everyone does that.